# How to import eclipse project from git to Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio

I have an android app codes in eclipse project stored in git server, and I want to import it into Android Studio.

Is there a way to retrieve the project from git directly into Android Studio? 
Is there a step-by-step instruction to achieve this?

Comment: The same user answers both questions, but the follow-up comments, each has its own merit towards our use. For those looking for answers on this specific subject, make sure to review the comments below before disregarding it as duplicate.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the step by step solution to do it.
You can use your eclipse code directory for it.

1. Open Android Studio -> Import Project-> Select your project directory. (In above case "MyApp")
   Remember Select the directory which contains Manifest file otherwise new "direct import wizard" doesn't 
   get triggered and android studio uses old import wizard.
2. Android Studio will create a copy of your project "MyApp_imported" with new directory structure.
3. Copy your existing ".git" directory inside "MyApp_imported"
4. Android Studio -> VCS -> Enable version control
   This will make Android Studio use your existing repository for imported project. Though imported project has 
   different directory structure but git handles them pretty well.
5. Android Studio -> Changes 
   Review all files and commit. Git will automatically handle new directory structure and file history etc will not be lost.
6. Now you can share it on github/Bitbucket by
   VCS-> Share it on GitHUb
   Note:- For bitbucket you will have to install "following Bitbucket plugin" for Android Studio. 
   http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6207?pr=androidstudio

Here are more details about it: [Import an eclipse android project with version control system into Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726041/import-an-eclipse-android-project-with-version-control-system-into-android-studi/24741026#24741026)

Comment: You saved me tons of hours with this explanation, thanks!!

Comment: I can't find the Changes Review all files option in Android Studio 1.0.1

Comment: @Garro88 Check Tab named "Changes" on left bottom of Android Studio

Comment: @ShaktiMalik ok I have found the tab, but now i have to commit all change or i have to do some operations? Soory but i am an Android Studio/Git noob =)

Comment: As explained above, Review files and commit. Note that you may want to ignore some file such as build and gen directory etc.

Comment: I found the bitbucket plugin referenced here is out of date.  You can find the most recent plugin https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads

Comment: what should i do to lots of changes appear from git status??

Comment: @user2273146 Check-in all of those changes.

Comment: I have not tried this yet, but if the directory structure is different then I can't see how you could go back to a version of your app that *preceded* the move from Eclipse to Android Studio.  And if you can't go back, then what is the advantage of using this approach rather than just starting over with a fresh git archive?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of months ago I got my job as android developer.The first problem i had faced were my collegues who using Eclipse.I was allowed to use Android studio if I will not make any changes to existing project structure.After 3-4 attemps I finally found a decision.Here is steps to open Eclipse git project without migrating to Gradle and without changing project structure.

1. Clone git repository of project
2. Add /gen and /.idea to .gitignore
3. Open any of already created Android Studio projects.
4. File -> Open -> Choose path root project folder(with src and res inside)
5. Doble-click project to open project structure
6. Select root project folder -> F4
7. Project -> Project SDK -> Android API XX Platform && Project language level -> Override in  interfaces
8. Modules -> Sources tab. Mark src as Sources && res as Resources.
9. Modules -> Paths tab. Use module compile output path.Create folders output and output_test inside gen folder (create gen if folder not exist yet).Output paths should look like C:\Users\User\project_rep\project\gen\output
10. Modules -> Dependencies tab. Click "+" -> Jars or directories.Select all .jar libraries which are using by your project.(Android Studio can pretend like its added only one jar but thats not true)
11. Facets -> "+" ->  Android
12. Facets -> Structure tab -> Reset to defaults.
13. Close Project Structure window.
14. Run -> Edit configurations -> Android Application -> Module -> Select your module.Target device -> Show chooser dialog.

Finally, after all of those steps you are able to hit Run button.Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can start checking if [this tutorial can help](http://wii.logdown.com/posts/2013/11/15/android-studio-git-tutorial), after enabling Git in Android Studio:

[image: http://user-image.logdown.io/user/756/blog/753/post/159805/aW22jGw0QgO4H5wlqRBd_git%20tool%20test.PNG]

If you then import into [Android Studio your Eclipse project](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) (already in a cloned git repo), you should see the Git options available for your project files.

Comment: The import part is quite straight forward, the unknown part is migrating from eclipse project into Android Studio within Android Studio. From Ant build to Gradle build, or anyway to support Ant build inside. I was asking for the whole enchilada.

Comment: @SeanLee I faced exact same issue and i solved it. I have written a step by step solution for it as an answer above. Please let me know if you have some doubts